# UndoHandling exception

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, publishing, deployer

When publishing a page, I am seeing the following exception. Any clue?

> ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stack trace for transaction: tcm:0-745476-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-745476-66560
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.handleFailure(PreCommitPhase.java:131) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.execute(PreCommitPhase.java:111) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:198) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:100) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_121]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_121]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_121]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_121]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_121]
>   Caused by: com.tridion.storage.persistence.undo.UndoHandlingException: An error occured while invoking method 'public abstract void com.tridion.storage.dao.PageDAO.create(com.tridion.data.CharacterData,java.lang.String) throws com.tridion.broker.StorageException' for dao com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPAPageDAO@3145888
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.undo.methodhandlers.AbstractMethodHandlerForUndo.buildUndoException(AbstractMethodHandlerForUndo.java:56) ~[cd_undo.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.undo.methodhandlers.WriteMethodHandlerForUndo.invokeMethod(WriteMethodHandlerForUndo.java:68) ~[cd_undo.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.undo.methodhandlers.UndoProxyMethodHandler.invoke(UndoProxyMethodHandler.java:61) ~[cd_undo.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.dao.PageDAO_$$_javassist_37.create(PageDAO_$$_javassist_37.java) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.PageWorker.doDeploy(PageWorker.java:74) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.model.transaction.TransactionLogItemWorker.doWork(TransactionLogItemWorker.java:27) ~[cd_model.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.runPrepare(PreCommitPhase.java:155) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.execute(PreCommitPhase.java:101) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       ... 10 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.undo.methodhandlers.ExecuteAnnotationOperation.executeRead(ExecuteAnnotationOperation.java:89) ~[cd_undo.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.undo.methodhandlers.WriteMethodHandlerForUndo.invokeMethod(WriteMethodHandlerForUndo.java:44) ~[cd_undo.jar:na]
>       ... 16 common frames omitted

Comment: Looks like you may have Undo enabled, and not fully configured? Check your deployer's storage conf.

Comment: Which version of SDL Web/Tridion are you using? AFAIK, deployer undo functionality was dropped in SDL Web 8.

Comment: We are using Tridion 2013 SP1. Also as suggested by @NunoLinhares, we are looking for Undo configuration.

Comment: Hi GVK,We are also Intermediately facing same issue, Can you please share how you resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like one of the component presentations in the page has wrong component template (not a DXA CT). You can either use the template builder or preview each of the components in the page in CME to identify the errors.